# insert into DB variable after an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named OPERATORI and anothe one calle OPERATORI DEFUNTI

parsing an xml I'm able to put id and name in OPERATORI but I need to put also in OPERATORI DEFUNTI the same ID I put in OPERATORI

here is my code:

```
 $results = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM OPERATORI");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) 
 {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO OPERATORI DEFUNTI VALUES ('$row','')";
 mysql_query($sql);
 }
```

But the result in OPERATORI DEFUNTI IS array,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row
```

is an array. To insert the ID into table. You need to do this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO OPERATORI DEFUNTI VALUES ('$row[ID]','')";
```

**Edit**

As of PHP version 5.5, the use of mysql extension is deprecated. You might want to use **mysqli** or **pdo** (To compare both, read [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

And as mentioned in the comment, it's not safe to execute query by joining value to it. Use prepare statement for it. Look at [mysqli::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) depends on your choice.

Comment: thanks a lot it works!another similar question: if I've 3 varibles (like NAME, MAIL and USERNAME) and I'd like to search the value in the DB I must do     while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($results) && $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($results) && $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) $sql = "INSERT INTO OPERATORI DEFUNTI VALUES ('".$row1["USERNAME"]."','".$row2["NAME"]."','".$row3["MAIL"]."')";
?

Comment: Though, it's not recommendedd due to security issue, you can do something like 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO OPERATORI DEFUNTI VALUES ('$row1[USERNAME]','$row2[NAME]','$row3[MAIL]');

Comment: @user2120473 Sorry but I don't quite understand your question. Is it you want to assign a value to $NAME? Providing the actualy parser error will be helpful too.